# Migrate workflow and activity from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation

Any one has recommendation, links to how to migrate workflow 3.5 to 4.0?

Any issues to look for, does MS provide some tool to facilitate migration? Or the only was is to re-write the whole thing ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a migration toolkit on CodePlex [here](http://wf.codeplex.com/). There is also an Interop activity in the box so yu can use some WF3 activities in WF4 as is.

That said WF4 is a completely new codebase with a very different design and migration is, in most cases, not a realistic option.