# Using workflow foundation 3.5 workflow in .net 4.0 project

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to convert quite big project from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0 and we have wwf 3.5 in it. Googling [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027572/migrate-workflow-and-activity-from-net-3-5-to-net-4-0) i realized that i would need to rewrite workflow almost from scratch. so my question is , if i can use .net 3.5 workflow in .net 4.0 project ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.  WF4 doesn't replace WF3.  [They are in different namespaces.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kushals/wf3-design-time-performance-i) The blog post isn't on topic, but the blogger is and he states this fact.

Comment: thank you for this link , it also answers some other questions i had

Answer (score 3):

As Will said, the WF3 stack is still present and supported in .NET 4 so you don't have to migrate your workflows to WF4. That said all future efforts will go towards WF4 so sooner or later you will probably have to bite the bullet. For now you don't have to though.